# Launch Linux terminal from Matlab

Tags: linux, matlab

I want to launch a Linux terminal from a Matlab script in order to run an object file from the terminal. After launching the terminal the Matlab script has to continue.

I have tried both the `unix()` and `system()` commands, but in both the Matlab script gets stuck in the terminal script and doesn't continue.

Is there a way for a Matlab script to launch a terminal, run an executable file on it and have the Matlab script continue with the rest of the script?

Comment: Do you really want a terminal emulator window (e.g. KDE's Konsole), or do you just want to run a program? By "object file" I guess you mean compiled executable? But then why do you talk about a "terminal script"? And what does "gets stuck" mean?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You dont have to open a terminal in order to execute a program...
You can simply run the executable from the matlab script using the `system` command.
[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/241352) is an example how to do it...
I think its a simpler way...:)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
The `system()` command runs the executable from the Matlab command window and doesn't allow for the Matlab script to continue, so I don't think this works for me.

Comment: I want to run a program that connects a device through ethernet. This program can be called from the terminal. The Matlab script would have to open a terminal, call the program and continue with its script. 
By 'stuck' I mean that the Matlab script doesn't continue when calling the program with `unix()` or `system()`. It gets stuck in the program. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: @LuisMendo: Great, that is just what I needed!!

I would like for the terminal to open as it displays useful information, is there a way to see the terminal too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return to Matlab immediately after starting the external process, add `&` at the end of the string passed to `system`. For example

```
system('filename &')
```

Comment: Great, that is just what I needed!! I would like for the terminal to open as it displays useful information, is there a way to see the terminal too?

Comment: I don't use Linux very often. Perhaps `system('sh filename &')`?

Comment: Or maybe `str = evalc('system(''filename &'')')` to get the output in string `str`; see [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2010/05/17/calling-shell-commands-from-matlab/)

Comment: I'm glad this was useful. Let me know which of my above comments worked to incorporate it in the answer

Comment: @user2835098 Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to launch a separate terminal application such as **terminal, gnome-terminal, xterm, konsole,** etc ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the)) providing the **-e** flag followed by the command you want to run. Something like this:

```
system('gnome-terminal -e ''your command here'' &')
```